# skype wrapper on ubuntu 15.04x64

Tags: skype

Trying to install skype wrapper on lastest ubuntu release.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa

Then:
sudo apt-get update
And I've have:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/skype-wrapper/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: The PPA doesn't have any packages for Vivid. May be you have to wait, or may be it has been abandoned.

Comment: Maybe theres another way to see skype icon in the unity tray?

Answer (score 2):

I've found sollution that helps me 
install `sudo apt-get install sni-qt sni-qt:i386`
and just restart skype